# Would a double to int type conversion be considered implicit type conversion?

Tags: java, implicit-conversion

Let's say I converted double x to an int, which can be done automatically through truncation. Would this be considered implicit conversion still? Is implicit conversion not being able to translate the actual value from one type to another type without losing any accuracy to that value. In this case would I not be losing the decimal part to x's value? I could not find anything specific in the [java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html) about this, so I thought to ask here:

```
double x = 420.69;
int y = x;
```

Comment: That's not an implicit conversion, that's an error. `int y = x;` won't compile.

Comment: In the documentation it is covered in [paragraph 5.1.3 Narrowing Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3).  Such conversion is possible due to **explicit** casting of a _wider_ type to the _narrower_ one.

Comment: Implicit conversion is the opposite of explicit conversion. Explicit conversion uses the casting rules, so ``int y = (int)x;`` would be explicit. Implicit conversion lacks the casting which means that the programmer could have made a mistake.

Answer (score 3):

That is not an implicit conversion and this will result to compiler error.

```
double x = 420.69;
int y = x;
```

Since double is a bigger data type than int, it needs to be down-casted.

```
double x = 420.69;
int y = (int)x;
```

However,all the digits after the decimal will be lost.